# Java SFTP client application in Cloud Foundary Environment

Tags: java, cloud, jsch, cloud-foundry

I have a java application ,which trasfters a file to SFTP server.
Our application use [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java) for implementation of sftp client in java.

Jsch requires below parameters to connect to a SFTP server:

```
Host name of SFTP server: XX.XX.XXX.XXX
Port : 22
Username : abc
Password : ****
```

My application is working fine and transferring the file when I deploy it on Unix boxes or run in my local machine.

**Now I am going to deploy the application on Cloud Foundry, but this is giving me ConnectException.**

```
2018-03-14T19:07:40.41+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I have updated the security group :

```
{
    "destination": "XX.XX.XXX.XXX",
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "ports": "22"
   }
```

PS:

1. "protocol": "sftp" is invalid ,so I gave "protocol": "tcp"
2. Cloud foundary(Private cloud) and SFTP server both are in my local premises.
3. I read about [volume services](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/running/deploy-vol-services.html)  but ,I did not find any clue. We do not have marketplace accessible, so If volume service can help then we will have to build those service.

**Queries:**

**How can I access my SFTP server via a application which is deployed on Cloud Foundry?**

Comment: "Connection refused" is a pretty standard error message. Do you know what it means in this context? What research did you do?

Comment: +1 seems like you just can't connect to the SFTP server.  Do `cf ssh` into your app container, then try running `ssh blah` and connecting to your server.  Does that work?  If not continue network troubleshooting.  For what it's worth, your application security group looks OK, that should allow outbound TCP on port 22 to that IP so it's probably not your ASG that's blocking the connection.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Mikusa .You My ASG settings are right.After updating security groups I redeployed the application .Now the application is able to connect with the sftp server. I did not know that we need to redeploy the application after updating the security group.